# Disable Bootstrap in Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I installed woocommerce and the product data tabs are invisible because of a bootstrap style conflict.

I don't know why wordpress takes enqueued styles and applies them to the admin panel.

How do I prevent an enqueued style from being applied to wp-admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assure you [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) does not use nor load [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) in either front-end or back-end of WordPress. In fact, in order to wrap WooCommerce templates in Twitter Bootstrap classes, one would need to install a special plugin for it: [WooCommerce TwitterBootstrap](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/woocommerce-twitterbootstrap/) (which looks abandoned).

It must be some other plugin that's loading it. Are you sure it's Twitter Bootstrap that's causing the conflict? Please note there are a lot of WooCommerce extensions which are in fact separate plugins.

You can view a full list of installed plugins in WordPress dashboard. If you want to find the culprit, disable them one by one.

Comment: I'm using twitter bootstrap for my css styles. I enqueue it in my functions.php so I can use it in my templates. Do you know how to set enqueued styles so they don't apply to wp-admin?

Comment: Yes. You use different action hooks: `admin_enqueue_scripts` for admin, `wp_enqueue_scripts` for front and `login_enqueue_scripts` for login.

Comment: wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' ); is what I am using. Yet it gets applied to the admin. I have all plugins, except woocommerce, disabled.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Which hook are you loading `wp_enqueue_style()` on?

Comment: You are confusing the `wp_enqueue_style()` / `wp_enqueue_script()` - which are ***functions*** with `wp_enqueue_scripts` which is an ***action hook***. See [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#combining-enqueue-functions) on how to wrap script/style enqueueing into a function that is called on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

Comment: This totally fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

By default, WooCommerce plugin doesn't use Bootstrap and shouldn't load the styles or scripts in your WordPress dashboard.

You have a plugin or theme that make it to load the Bootstrap framework in your WordPress. Try to disable the active plugins one by one or check in their source code which styles or scripts they load. I will suggest to check the `functions.php` file of your theme too.